# Django: $ python manage.py runserver

Tags: python, django, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I was just setting up the virtual environment with Django for my first time. And I couldn't find any resources for this issue.

When I was in virtual environment, in the same directory as the manage.py file, I type in the command:

```
python manage.py runserver
```

I can't get the development server up and running. Instead, I got the error:

```
Segmentation fault
```

I tried some solutions but nothing good happened.

```
python -vvvvv manage.py runserver

python manage.py migrate
```

I'm using python 3.6.1 and django 1.10.5

EDIT: I had to downgrade python to 3.5.3 and it worked!

Comment: Which operating system is this running on?

Comment: Have you activated the virtual environment?

Comment: Isn't that a VM client by any chance?

Comment: I found the solution. I had to downgrade python to 3.5.3 and it worked!

To answer some questions above: 
It's on Windows 10.
The virtual environment was activated.
I haven't used VM.